# How to write a query to see who called who the most in an Access database of phone calls?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-access

I have a phone bill in Excel that shows all calls made to and from my phone and I imported it into a table in Access 2007. I want to learn to use Access to do a simple query to determine who I talk to the most.

Say we have Column A (caller) and Column B (person being called), and that my number will always be in either column. How do I make a query in Access to determine which phone number I talk the most with? I've got the Table with the Excel data in it, but I need some step-by-step handholding to learn how to do the query.

In simple english, I want to query all phone calls that contain my number in either column A or column B. Then, I want to count each unique pair (mynumber + othernumber or othernumber + mynumber should be counted under the same pair). Then, I want to count/summarize each unique pair to see which pair yields the highest count.

E.g. Go to Create ribbon, click Query Wizard, etc...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly and easily see the numbers that called you or you called with a GROUP BY query.

`SELECT Caller from phonebook GROUP BY CALLER or SELECT [Person being called] from phonebook GROUP BY [person being called]`

If you want to merge the two columns you must use a UNION query.

`SELECT Caller AS A FROM phonebook UNION ALL SELECT [person being called] AS A from phonebook.  Save that query.  In a new query type SELECT A FROM [new query name] GROUP BY A`

Perhaps studying SQL would be a good idea. [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql) is a good resource

Comment: Transactional SQL is so much fun!